# Sentinel not working how its supposed to?

Tags: c

In this code the person has to enter y if wishes to continue, but why does it ask him the question two times when he enters y.

```
char c = 'y';
while(c!='n'){
    printf("Do you wish to continue: (y or n):");
    c = getchar();
}
```

[Here is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZAzq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does it ask him the question two times when he enters y

The enter key the user hits is taken as another character (a new-line: `\n`)  as well.

Comment: i removed the new line character still not working, its asks again two times.

Comment: @Marko I am referring to the "*enter key the **user** hits*" to make the `y` go into the program, not the one the program printed! :)

Answer (score 1):

getchar() gives c the value 'y' at first and then the value of '\n'.